# visual c# express reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, report, visual-c#-express-2010, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am using visual c# 2010 express edition and sql server 2008 R2 Express to develop a software. Now I need to create reports in c# based on the data that is stored in the sql database.

Based on this link : [SQL 2008 R2 Express install option](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx)

I have the version "Database with Management Tools" installed. That is, the one which is 235 MB.

Now my requirements are that the software, which is written in c#, must be able to generate reports based on the data that is found in the sql database.

My questions are:

1. Must I install the Database with Advanced Services version (727 MB) to be able to use the MS SQL Reporting services?
2. Considering that I am using express editions for both c# and sql server, will I be able to make my software use the reporting services of MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Express? I have no experience in this but I have read somewhere that report viewer is not available in the express edition. Will that prevent me from using the reporting services?
3. If not, do you guys have any recommendations to other reporting tools that I might use? I need to generate reports containing graphs (free tools as long as possible, this is my dissertation project).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with full Reporting Services: I'd consider using the [ReportViewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) in local mode in my app instead

This means you don't need SSRS installed at all: it's embedded in your app.

Comment: 1. Will I be able to build graph?
2. Will I be able to use this in c# express?

Sorry for so much questions.

Comment: Yes, in the link. Here is the target of the link http://www.gotreportviewer.com/charts/index.htm And yes to c# express